# How to build custom designed zoom-in zoom-out on map i?

Tags: angular, dictionary, zooming

I want to build custom designed zoom-in zoom-out that means I want to change the design of zoom in and zoom out buttons and want to add image instead of + and - icon on map in angular?

I removed that by default zoom in zoom out and added 2 buttons as I wanted. Now I want to add function so that zoom-in & zoom-out buttons can work properly

Answer (score 0):

First need to defined the map in a variable, then you can set the zoom with setZoom and getZoom function.

```
For Example:
this.map = (here defined the map)

//ZoomIn 
zoomIn() {
    this.map.setZoom(this.map.getZoom() + 1);
}
//ZoomOut
zoomOut() {
 this.map.setZoom(this.map.getZoom() - 1)
}
```

I think this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```js
zoom(count){
    const view = this.map.getView();
    const zoom = view.getZoom();
    view.animate({ zoom: zoom + count})
  }
  
  //stop default zoom-in & zoom-out to be worked
  loadMap = () => {
      controls: [],
  }
```

```css
 #zoomin {
        background-color: var(--white);
        border: none;
        color: black;
        padding: 2px 20px;
        font-size: 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
        /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #888888; */
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
      }

      #zoomout{
        background-color: var(--white);
        border: none;
        color: black;
        padding: 2px 20px;
        font-size: 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
        /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #888888; */
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
      }
```

```html
<button mat-raised-button id="zoomin" (click)="zoom(-1)"
            style="z-index: 1;height: 45px; position: absolute;right: 10px;margin-top: 150px;">
            <i style="margin-left: -9px;"class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i>
        </button>
        <button mat-raised-button id="zoomout" (click)="zoom(+1)"
            style="z-index: 1;height: 45px; position: absolute;right: 10px;margin-top: 196px;">
            <i style="margin-left: -9px;" class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
```